# Immediately render data from fetch with React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm having troubles rendering data from a fetch request. I have a `getUser` function that calls `useState(setUsers)` and I would like to map that state to render a list of the data I've fetched.

Obviously it doesn't work and I don't if it's because when I call

```
{
    users.map((user,index) => {
         <option key={index}>{user.username}</option>
    })
}
```

in the return the state of users has not been updated yet.

Here's the code:

```
export default function NewChannel() {

    let {authToken, user, logout} = useContext(AuthContext)
    let [users, setUsers] = useState([])

    useEffect(
        ()=>{

            let getUsers = async () => {
                console.log(user)
                let response = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/user`, {
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + String(authToken.access)
                    },
                })
                let data = await response.json()
                if(response.status === 200){
                    setUsers(data)
                }else{
                  alert('You have been logged out')
                  logout()
                }
              }
              getUsers()
              console.log('users',users)
        }, []
    )

    return (
        <div>
            <div className='new-channel-form'>
                <select>
                    {
                        users.map((user,index) => {
                            <option key={index}>{user.username}</option>
                        })
                    }
                </select>
                <input className="submit-button" type="submit"/>
            </div>
        </div>

    )
}
```

The console.log the end of useEffect actually log the fetched data

Comment: Did you mean `return <option key={index}>{user.username}</option>`? You don't have a return statement, and you aren't using the arrow function shorthand.

Comment: Lol maybe it's getting late for coding... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem with

```
users.map((user,index) => {
  return <option key={index}>{user.username}</option>
})
```

or

```
users.map((user,index) => (
  <option key={index}>{user.username}</option>
))
```